# CRM Plug in is not firing from SSIS

Tags: dynamics-crm

We are trying to migrate data to CRM 4.0 using SSIS. CRM contains a plug in that works perfectly from the UI, however, SSIS is not firing the plug-in when records are created. The plug-in is registered for Update and Create and both are pre-stage. Both are synchronous. Both are for server and not offline. Pipeline is parent. 
Anyone have any Ideas?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Plug-ins will not fire for operations directly against the SQL database.  You must use mechanisms which work against the web services for your plug-ins to fire.  CRM has a couple of import functions:

[The Import functions through their web-ui](https://web.archive.org/web/20151215192519/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/crm/archive/2008/03/07/importing-data-in-crm-4-0-made-easier.aspx?) and the [Data Migration Manager](https://web.archive.org/web/20101209074616/http://www.microsoft.com:80/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=6766880A-DA8F-4336-A278-9A5367EB79CA) (download for the SDK).  Here is [SDK coverage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamics-crm4/developers-guide/cc150977%28v=msdn.10%29).

I'm actually not 100% sure whether the DMM goes against the web services or not.

Comment: Spot on.  For emphasis, direct database writes are unsupported!  Use one of the three methods above.

Comment: Sorry forgot to include that the API is being used within SSIS. I'm thinking some kind of security issue. But it could be something else because the security appears to be set up properly.. Thanks for the first answer

Comment: Have you tried looking at Settings -> System Jobs to see if they are failing?  Doing an Advanced Find on System Jobs and adding the Message and Message Name columns can be enlightening.

Comment: Ah I see <http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2008/05/07/integrating-crm-using-sql-integration-services-ssis.aspx>.  So you know your plugins work using the UI forms.  1.  Are your records created on the import or do they fail?  2.  If you were to register a workflow for create of the entity, does that fire?  3.  Can we see some of the code for SSIS and/or one of the plugins not firing?

Comment: Thanks benjynito..Yes the plug-in does work using the UI forms. The code does not belong to me and I'm working in the dark. Our firm wrote and tested the plug-in. The data migration was not our responsibility, but of course when it doesn't fire it becomes our responsibility. This is the plug-in code

Comment: I'm willing to bet even though SSIS COULD cause web services to fire, they're going directly into the tables and not at the web services.  I've yet to hit a scenario where my plug-in's don't fire when the web services are used.  I'd work with the SSIS authors referencing the blog posted for a proper integration.